# how does the Cin and Cout objects work in a loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, iostream, cin

I have this piece of code

```
int main()
{
   char ch;
   while (cin >> ch)
     cout << ch;
   return 0;
}
```

What I'm wandering is how does `cin` work in the `while()` loop? I mean, does it have an inner index to were it left off?

Comment: ``cin`` works like a buffer. When you input data it gets stored in a queue. When you read data from ``cin`` the data in the queue or buffer (however you want to call it) gets removed.

Comment: An inner index? Why yes it does! Read more here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you enter data, the loop will continue, it will only stops when find EOF (End of File)  `ctrl + C` (in windows)  `ctrl + D` (in linux)

This is usefull when you need to test a lot of cases and you don't know for sure how many are, you can enter how many times you want, the program will only stops when the end of file is found!

Example Input

```
a
b
c
(ctrl + d)
```

Example Output

```
a
b
c
the program will finish because EOF was found!
```

See this reference:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/EOF/